Notation for pullbacks for a set family
For two morphisms $f_1 \colon A_1 \to Z$ and $f_2 \colon A_2 \to Z$, the pullback is written as
$$ A_1 \times_{Z} A_2 \; ,$$
or sometimes even
$$ A_1 \times_{f_1,Z,f_2} A_2 \; . $$
If i have a set family $ (A_i)_{i \in I}$ and a family of morphisms $f_i \colon A_i \to Z$, what is a useful notation for the pullback of that?  Is there something like
$$\prod_{Z} (A_i)_{i \in I} \quad, \qquad \text{or} \qquad \prod_{(f_i)_{i \in I}, Z} A_i \qquad \text{?}$$
Notes:

This is nothing more than the limit over a functor $J \to \mathcal C$, where the index category (or "diagram") $J$ is the directed graph ("diagram") $G = (I \sqcup \{ \ast \}, \{ (i,\ast) \mid i \in I \})$, which is a star graph where all non-root nodes $i \in I$ point to the root node $\ast$.


I think you already answered your question:  it's $\mathrm{Lim} F$ for a suitable functor $F$.

If you want a capital Pi-notation, I would use something like $\prod\limits_{i\in I}{}_ZA_i$, but I have no clue how to properly typeset this in LaTeX. The idea should be that this is an actual product in the slice category over $Z$.

@Randall yes, but that is not a nice notation.

@Berber Ask yourself: Are you really working with this in a way that would greatly benefit from concise notation? In that case either use what Thorgott suggests or come up with something on your own. Otherwise you should be happy with "let $X$ be the limit [...]" like the rest of us :). After all, almost no other co/limit gets special notation, and if they do it's largely because they play some distinguished role. Assigning special notation to everything you come across is not a virtue.

@BenSteffan Thank you for your comments!  I guess then I will just use my own notation, like the one from Thorgott, together with describing that this is the pullback.
Regarding "No other co/limit gets special notation":  I disagree.  products and coproducts get special notation, among a few others, and these are also defined over arbitrarily many, not just two.  pullbacks and pushouts also get a special notation, except these only with two objects (and the morphisms and the object over which to take the pullback/pushout).  hence my question.

@Berber I said almost no co/limits get special notation. You're free to disagree, of course, but you don't exactly list a plethora either, and those you list seem fit neatly under my category of "playing some distinguished role."

sorry, i overread "almost"
